# Fantasy story of a prince's unwanted brother

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I'm trying to remember the title of a fantasy story in which the main character is the unwanted brother (or half-brother?) of a prince. Other important characters are an older brother who is assassinated and a crippled stableman.

This story haunts me, as I never finished it. I believe it is part of a series I picked up at the library.

Comment: A little more data could help.. When did you pick the book up?  Any idea of the publishing date?  Any character names or anything?

Answer (score 9):

The [Farseer trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farseer_Trilogy#The_Farseer_Trilogy) by [Robin Hobb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Hobb) (who also writes as Megan Lindholm). The three volumes are *Assassin's Apprentice*, *Royal Assassin* and *Assassin's Quest*.

Comment: If this is the series you're looking for I highly recommend you let it keep haunting you.  The beginning of the series is much more interesting than the end.